# SSL Certificate not Working on Safari

Tags: windows, ssl, safari

We have our site setup to use SSL through a certificate from GoDaddy.com.  On every browser except Safari, there are no issues with SSL.  However, on Safari on a PC, we cannot access the site.  When you try to browse to the site, you either receive a "Select a Certificate" prompt or, a "No Certificate Available" prompt.  If you receive the "Select a Certificate" prompt and you choose a valid certificate, the prompt goes away and it looks like the page begins to load, but it just hangs indefinitely.

I have already spoken at length with GoDaddy and they have confirmed that there is not an issue with SSL or the certificate chain.

The server that hosts the site is running Windows Server 2008 - IIS 7.
The issue has been reproduced on the latest version of Safari (5.1.7).

This is working fine on a MAC.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The site is https://www.nextcrew.com

Comment: Sounds like you should stop requesting a TLS client certificate.

Comment: How do you stop requesting a TLS certificate?

Answer (score 2):

```
    <Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               port="8443" maxThreads="200"
               scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
               SSLCertificateFile="conf/ssl/server.cer"
               SSLCertificateKeyFile="conf/ssl/server.key"
               SSLVerifyClient="none" SSLProtocol="SSLv3"/>
```

`SSLVerifyClient="optional"` does not work in Safari for Windows.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you expand your explanation? Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! I think that it's problem with Safari for Windows OS. It appears that it doing negotiate client certificates improperly with the web server.

Comment: Can you cite a source for your claim that SSLVerifyClient=optional doesn't work in Safari/Windows? Is it a bug, or by design?

Comment: Has this been resolved ? I have the same issue now but not sure where do I make the above change or set SSLVerifyClient="none". Any idea where I could make the above change ?